# Limit of two varriable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How to compute the following problem of  limit

$$1. \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0) }\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}}{x-y},$$

$$2.\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1) }\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}}{x-y},$$

where  x and y both are variables and  $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Try different paths like f(t,-t) och f (t,0) ect . if you find different values then you can conclude that the limit don't exist.

Comment: We can not use f(t,-t),  because after using it, negative sign is obtained in one of the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}}{x-y}= \frac{x(1-x)-y(1-y)}{(x-y)(\sqrt{x(1-x)}+\sqrt{y(1-y)})}= \frac{1-x-y}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}+\sqrt{y(1-y)}}
\end{align}